# Complex where clause with multiple joins in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's say I have a database where I am tracking statistics for several soccer leagues.  My tables and relevant columns are as follows.

leagues: id
teams: id, league_id
players: id, team_id
goals: id, player_id, num_goals

As you can see, this is essentially a series of hasManyThrough relationships.  A league has many players through teams.  A team has many goals through players.  Etc.  Where I'm breaking down is in writing a query that sums the number of goals by league.  My best effort so far is something like this:

```
select('id', 'name') from leagues,
join teams where ('teams.id' = 'leagues.id'),
join players where ('players.id' = 'teams.id'),
join goals where ('goals.id' = 'players.id'),
sum('goals.num_goals');
```

The goal of that query was to return an array of league id, league name, and the number of goals scored by players in that league.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your joins are ok, the problem is with how you do the sum.

Sum statment should be in the `select` statement, and preferably come with with `group by` statement. you also shouldn't wrap column names with ' signs

```
select leagues.id, leagues.name, sum(goals.num_goals) from leagues
  join teams on teams.id = leagues.id
  join players on players.id = teams.id
  join goals on goals.id = players.id
group by leagues.id, leagues.name;
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you.